# Obsolete attribute doesn't cause any compiler warning in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, obsolete

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. But find that the Obsolete attribute doesn't cause any compiler warning (I want it to cause a compiler warning). 
The warning level is 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [obsolete attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) will cause a compiler warning when you try to use the class/method that's marked with it. For example the following causes a warning:

```
[Obsolete("some obsolete message")]
class Foo { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

while this doesn't:

```
[Obsolete("some obsolete message")]
class Foo { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { }
}
```